# SharePoint Top Link Bar Tab Color & Site Pages

Tags: 2010, publishing, top-link-bar, site-settings

I'm having a problem with the "Top Link Bar" navigation. I have a certain amount of tabs in the top link bar with Site Pages behind them.

Only the first tab colors blue (the home tab). I want the right tab to color blue if I navigate to the page.

I activated the publishing features so I get the extra navigation settings menu.

I read if you use relative urls the right tab colors blue if you are on the page that links to it, I tried this but unsuccessful.

Any help is welcome.

[image: PrintScreenTabs]

Comment: can you put some screenshot of your current top link bar? it will be helpful to understand.

Comment: So under the first tab you will find the home page. The other tabs refer to site pages. I navigated with the second tab to the page behind it and the tab does not turn blue. 

I know that it's possible to have this tab turn blue so it show that you are on that page under that tab. But I cannot figure it out how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there may be something with the CSS for this. Have you making a CSS file with this included:

```
.s4-toplinks .s4-tn A.selected {
    background: <whatever settings you want>;
}
```

I was playing with that on my preprod site and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Late answer but this has been put on hold for myself for a while. I will try this later and approve this answer if I see this trick did it for me.